# Is MSVBVM60.DLL included in every version of Windows after XP?

Tags: windows, winapi, vb6, windows-xp

I had to write a small non-.NET application, so I did it in VB6.
My app works on Windows 8.1 and XP, but what about Windows Server? Do all versions of Windows, since XP have the runtime preinstalled?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx

Comment: So it seems it has full support. Thanks for the link.

Comment: About the only time you won't find it preinstalled is a very old Windows 95/98 that never had IE 5.x installed, or a 64-bit server OS that doesn't have any of the WOW64 subsystem installed.  Basically it's a universal part of 32-bit Windows and has been for a long, long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Long answer: the VB6 runtime is [officially supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx) as an integral part of Windows in Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 including R2, Windows 7, and Windows 8.

Comment: And Windows 10. I checked the Technical Preview.